# How to insert a spreadsheet in Google Form?

Tags: forms, google-sheets, google-forms, survey

I want to play a prediction game for the World Cup with some friends. The idea is that each of them should fill out a spreadsheet like [this one](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtHDyHP7H3XQntFK-EkVSXaUeMJD0A?e=5cUazq) and I would receive the answers, and they also receive a backup. How can I insert it in a Google Form (or something similar) to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could send them the spreadsheet you have created, ask them to complete it and send it back. You could then put each of the files into Google Sheets with one sheet per person plus an overview sheet that shows everyone's predictions. Then you can just share this file so everyone can see each other's guesses?

If you wanted to use Google Forms then building something like this would work (I've just said each team can score between 0 and 10 goals but you could change the maximum limit):

[image: Multiple choice grid question example on Google Forms]

This would then give you one row per person and one column per team in each match in Google Sheets. You could then input this data into another Google Sheet to share with your friends and to reformat/present it how you want.
[image: Google Forms output in Google Sheets]

Comment: By sending the spreadsheet I created, I'd have to create one link for each person, right?

Comment: Is your spreadsheet an Excel file (.xlsx) or an Excel Online file?

Comment: it could be both..There's no constraint about it

Comment: It'd be better to send them an Excel file (.xlsx) and they complete their own local version. Otherwise you'd have to make each of them their own Excel Online or Google Sheets file